# Bluetooth does not auto-connect to vehicle after update to android 11

Tags: bluetooth, android-11, oxygenos, oneplus-6

After updating a OnePlus 6 device to Android 11, I noticed that the bluetooth, when turned on, does not automatically connect to the car, but I have to select it manually.
I don't find any option to enable this feature, before the update everything was working fine.
The update in question is [OxygenOS 11](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/oxygenos-11-for-the-oneplus-6-and-oneplus-6t.1482290/) (stable).